# Change xml description of property in derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, xml-comments

Is there a way to change the xml description of a property in a derived class without rewriting getter and setter declaration?
Example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// description of foo in BaseClass
    /// </summary>
    public int foo
    {
        get { /* do something */ }
        set { /* do something */ }
    }
}

public sealed class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// description of foo in DerivedClass
    /// </summary>
    public int foo
    {
        get { /* do something */ }
        set { /* do something */ }
    }
}
```

Where the implementations of `foo` should be the same in both classes, only description changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically. You don't need to add new implementation, though - you can just use:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// description of foo in DerivedClass
/// </summary>
public int foo
{
    get { return base.foo; }
    set { base.foo = value = value; }
}
```

But you will need to re-declare the method. This could be via a `virtual` / `override` pair, or could be via a `new` (member-hiding) member.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing like this and I didn't know if there was a more compact way.